# Do statement 1 and 2 imply statement 3?

Tags: logic

> Statement 1 : All locks are safety tools
>
> Statement 2 : Some safety tools are chain
>
> Statement 3 : Some chain are not locks

I tried to answer this myself but i'm having a problem to decide the correct venn diagram for the statement "Some B are C"

I tried to draw both venn diagram, and want to know whether both scenarios are possible, or not. And if not, why is that?

[Diagram 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZ6hL.png)

[Diagram 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUsGz.png)

Also i still need the answer to the original question in the title. Do both statement 1 and 2 imply statement 3?

Comment: Why would $1,2$ imply $3$?  Suppose that all locks are chain and nothing else is a chain.  Then $1,2$ are true (at least, assuming locks exist) but $3$ is not.

Comment: If you have $Chain \subseteq Lock \subseteq Safety\, tools,$ then first two statements are true but third isn't.

Comment: thanks for the reply, this was actually a question from the test i did a few days ago, basically given the first 2 statement, we should choose another statement that would satisfy those two statement, and the "correct answer" happened to be the statement 3. I don't even agree with that, but that's the reason why i asked this here in the first place :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$L\subseteq S\land S\cap C\ne\emptyset\implies C\setminus L\ne\emptyset$$ is not true.

Indeed assume that there are only elements in $C\cap L\cap S$. Then the premises are verified, but the consequence is false.